# kubectl expose --type=LoadBalancer not working

Tags: kubernetes

I ran into some trouble getting an external ip address after posting the following json object (variables excluded):

```
$json= '{
          "kind": "Service",
          "apiVersion": "v1",
          "metadata": {
            "name": ""
          },
          "spec": {
            "ports": [{
              "port": 80,
              "targetPort": 80
            }],
            "selector": {
              "app": ""
            },
            "type": "LoadBalancer"
          }
}';
```

The service is created but no external ip is ever given.

Unable to determine where the issue lay, I proceeded to install a clean copy of kubernetes (and the cluster it is defined to install) using the following command provided in the documentation (V1 kubernetes/examples/simple-nginx.md):

```
curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash
```

This of course set things up automatically. I then ran the following commands to test if the LoadBalancer function was working:

```
kubectl run my-nginx --image=nginx --replicas=2 --port=80
```

After running `kubectl get pods` to confirm that they were ready, I exposed the service:

```
kubectl expose rc my-nginx --port=80 --type=LoadBalancer
```

I then ran `kubectl get service` for the past few minutes, and no public ip is being provided..

That cant be right?

**EDIT**

```
kubectl get services  

NAME         LABELS                                    SELECTOR       IP(S)          PORT(S)
kubernetes   component=apiserver,provider=kubernetes   <none>         10.0.0.1       443/TCP
my-nginx     run=my-nginx                              run=my-nginx   10.0.136.163   80/TCP


kubectl get service my-nginx -o yaml  

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2015-08-11T11:44:02Z
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
  name: my-nginx
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1795"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/services/my-nginx
  uid: 434751be-401e-11e5-a219-42010af0da43
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.x.xxx.xxx
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31146
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

After running (Thanks GameScripting):

```
kubectl describe service my-nginx
```

I saw the following error:

```
FirstSeen               LastSeen            Count   From            SubobjectPath   Reason              Message
  Tue, 11 Aug 2015 14:00:00 +0200   Tue, 11 Aug 2015 14:02:41 +0200 9   {service-controller }           creating loadbalancer failed    failed to create external load balancer for service default/my-nginx: googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'FORWARDING_RULES' exceeded.  Limit: 15.0
```

Comment: I guess I've had the same problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31897187/808723

Answer (score 4):

After manually removing the Forwarding Rules Under "Networking->Load Balancing->Network Load Balancing" (Or you can use `gcloud compute forwarding-rules delete`) I was able to get public Ip's again. It seems somehow the forwarding rules werent deleted and reached the limit. It is strange as when I ran `Kubectl stop service` it removed the forwarding rule for me.