# Kubernetes docker sample does not expose a port

Tags: docker, kubernetes

As I am exploring kubernetes I started with the docker based getting-started guide as suggested by the docs. The guide can be found here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/release-1.0/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md

Breaking down the guid, it suggests to run the following commands:

```
docker run --net=host -d gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.9 /usr/local/bin/etcd --addr=127.0.0.1:4001 --bind-addr=0.0.0.0:4001 --data-dir=/var/etcd/data
docker run --net=host -d -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2 /hyperkube kubelet --api_servers=http://localhost:8080 --v=2 --address=0.0.0.0 --enable_server --hostname_override=127.0.0.1 --config=/etc/kubernetes/manifests
docker run -d --net=host --privileged gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2 /hyperkube proxy --master=http://127.0.0.1:8080 --v=2

./kubectl -s http://localhost:8080 run-container nginx --image=nginx --port=80
./kubectl expose rc nginx --port=80
```

Those commands generate the following output on my machine:

```
5a0993be2df88f9da448234490ce98f744a47d0ff3ec2e9b9ba76ff8c85eb600
0c9ab039e8024d5596b87eb294ad31538ba8864509d9886c4217e6fe47416f1a
d413be16d3f0167bbaacba7582d22a1752b2195fe8d7f7333bbcb5ce2d2a7b20

CONTROLLER   CONTAINER(S)   IMAGE(S)   SELECTOR    REPLICAS
nginx        nginx          nginx      run=nginx   1

NAME      LABELS      SELECTOR    IP(S)     PORT(S)
nginx     run=nginx   run=nginx             80/TCP
```

I am now wondering why the "IP(S)" column does not show an ip-address.
Looking at my `docker ps` output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
4c5d8c790daa        nginx                                        "nginx -g 'daemon of   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                            k8s_nginx.d7d3eb2f_nginx-em03c_default_c7d89937-3df9-11e5-b322-20689deb710c_b7323a43                     
cedfe5cf7841        gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0         "/pause"               4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes                            k8s_POD.ef28e851_nginx-em03c_default_c7d89937-3df9-11e5-b322-20689deb710c_cf507bf9                       
a92be0abae29        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2   "/hyperkube schedule   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_scheduler.b725e775_k8s-master-127.0.0.1_default_9b44830745c166dfc6d027b0fc2df36d_85e00e91            
7910edc79350        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2   "/hyperkube apiserve   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_apiserver.70750283_k8s-master-127.0.0.1_default_9b44830745c166dfc6d027b0fc2df36d_03ed1050            
23d1d3f9eac0        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2   "/hyperkube controll   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_controller-manager.aad1ee8f_k8s-master-127.0.0.1_default_9b44830745c166dfc6d027b0fc2df36d_17695204   
caccad2f2e68        gcr.io/google_containers/pause:0.8.0         "/pause"               5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_POD.e4cc795_k8s-master-127.0.0.1_default_9b44830745c166dfc6d027b0fc2df36d_fb79862d                   
d413be16d3f0        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2   "/hyperkube proxy --   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            nostalgic_colden                                                                                         
0c9ab039e802        gcr.io/google_containers/hyperkube:v0.21.2   "/hyperkube kubelet    5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            suspicious_ritchie                                                                                       
5a0993be2df8        gcr.io/google_containers/etcd:2.0.9          "/usr/local/bin/etcd   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            loving_einstein2
```

i am wondering why the nginx-container has no port mappings.

**How can an kubernetes service route traffic into a docker container that does not expose any ports?** Is there anything what has changed since the documentation was written? Or is there anything I am missing?

**Versions used:**

`./kubectl version`:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"0", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v0.18.2", GitCommit:"1f12b893876ad6c41396222693e37061f6e80fe1", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"0", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v0.21.2", GitCommit:"4e89f2e6670b1662021a86ac42b99c5c50c37d05", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

`docker version`

```
Client version: 1.7.0
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 0baf609
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.0
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 0baf609
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `kubectl expose` command creates a service, however its selector does not match the created pods.

You can use `./kubectl expose rc nginx -l run=nginx --port=80` to create a service using `run=nginx` as the selector.

Then running `kubectl describe service nginx` shows:

```
W0809 14:05:26.337988    3423 request.go:291] field selector: v1beta3 - events - involvedObject.kind - Service: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
W0809 14:05:26.340098    3423 request.go:291] field selector: v1beta3 - events - involvedObject.uid - deb1c06e-3e8e-11e5-aa11-20689deb710c: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
W0809 14:05:26.340197    3423 request.go:291] field selector: v1beta3 - events - involvedObject.name - nginx: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
W0809 14:05:26.340243    3423 request.go:291] field selector: v1beta3 - events - involvedObject.namespace - default: need to check if this is versioned correctly.
Name:           nginx
Labels:         run=nginx
Selector:       run=nginx
Type:           ClusterIP
IP:         10.0.0.201
Port:           default 80/TCP
Endpoints:      172.17.0.29:80
Session Affinity:   None
No events.
```

When you now navigate to the endpoint at `172.17.0.29:80` you can see your  nginx running.

Answer (score 0):

For me the original sample was working properly (even though you don't get the IP listed in the expose command output). But I couldn't access it from outside. I had to add `--public-ip=` to the expose command and it worked like a charm (even though I still don't get the IP printed in the expose command output).

Answer (score 0):

I notice that if you use `kubectl expose rc nginx --port=80` than `kubectl describe service nginx` it shows:

```
...
Endpoints:      <none>
...
```

But if you wait some seconds and run `kubectl describe service nginx` again, it will show something like:

```
...
Endpoints:      172.17.0.7:80
...
```

Anyway it don't show the IP in the expose command output and you will need the `kubectl describe service nginx` command. Maybe the guide should be updated.